# Mysql - to much data in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 database tables - products & product_x_category and products table have 150 000 rows, product_x_category have probably 145 000 rows.

What is the best way to work with so much data in database?

For example, I try to get out of the database proructs that are not included in any category.

```
SELECT * FROM products where id NOT IN(SELECT product_id FROM product_x_category);
```

and X other methods what I know... - group concat, joins etc. but all queries are to long (20 sec +- or just db timeout)

Can anyone advise me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: 150000 Rows isn't really much, actually.

Comment: Check queries (explain), indexes etc. 150K rows isnt much

Comment: This definitely isn't enough information to go on, but my first instinct would be to use `explain [put your query here]` to see what kind of [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html) would help your query speed. As has been noted, this just isn't very much data as far as modern computing power is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` sometimes has better performance than `NOT IN`.  And, it behaves better when the subquery has `NULL` values. So, get used to writing:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_x_category pxc WHERE pxc.id = p.product_id);
```

Second, you want an index on `product_x_category(product_id)` for this query.

Finally, add a foreign key constraint so the products are correct in the `product_x_category` table:

```
alter table product_x_category add constraint fk_pxc_product_id foreign key (product_id) references products(id);
```

That way, you can only enter correct products into the table (and you'll want something similar for the category).

Note:  You might have a problem adding this to a table that already has data if the data is not consistent.

Comment: Thank you, that's great. The problem was in the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* from products a left join product_x_category b 
on a.id = b.product_id where b.product_id is NULL
```

.

This will give you records which are not present in product_x_category

Comment: You just need to select `a.*` here, also put the b.product_id IS NULL in a  where clause as it probably wont work in the `ON` part of the query.

Comment: Thank you sir, mine or @Gordon Linoff's query lasted about 0.8s and this query lasted about 0.08 (y), nice